# How to fix 'Segmentation Error' when there are no pointers?

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault

When I compile my code it works compiles with no errors, however when I run the code it gives the following error 'Segmentation Fault' with no more information. However when I have looked up Segmentation Fault, it normally has to do with pointers, and I haven't used pointers at all.

I have already looked through the whole thing for any typos where I may have said '&' instead of '&&' and so on. I also have looked the error up, and recompiled the code.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

std::string answer(int placement, std::vector<int> peopleInLinE, int Fifties, int twentyFives)
{
  if (((peopleInLinE[placement] - 25) % (Fifties * 50)) == 0)
  {
    Fifties -= peopleInLinE[placement] / (Fifties * 50);
  } else if (((peopleInLinE[placement] - 25) % (twentyFives * 25)) == 0)
  {
    twentyFives -= peopleInLinE[placement] / (twentyFives * 25);
  } else if (peopleInLinE[placement] == 100)
  {
    if (Fifties >= 1 && twentyFives >= 1)
    {
      Fifties -= 1;
      twentyFives -= 1;
    } else if (twentyFives >= 3)
    {
      twentyFives -= 3;
    } else {
      return "NO";
    }
  } else {
    return "NO";
  }
  return "YES";
}

std::string tickets(const std::vector<int> peopleInLine){
  int twentyFiveS;
  int FiftieS;

  for (int placemenT; peopleInLine.size(); placemenT++)
  {
    if (answer(placemenT, peopleInLine, FiftieS, twentyFiveS) == "NO") {
      return "NO";
    }
  }
  return "YES";
}
int main() {
  std::cout << tickets({25, 50, 100, 25});
  return 0;
}
```

The reason why a few of the variables have random capitals, is because I didn't know if it was saying that the two things have the exact same spelling, so they are the same thing, so I changed the spelling to try to figure it out.

This code is for the "Vasya - Clerk" challenge on Codewars, I included the whole file, because I have no clue where the error might be.

The only error message I have gotten is "Segmentation Fault" with no other explanation.

Comment: what is this `for (int placemenT; peopleInLine.size(); placemenT++)`?

Comment: Are you asking why it has weird capitals?

Comment: `placemenT` has also indeterminate value, because you did not initialize it, there's also an infinite loop if `peopleInLine.size() > 0`, you might want `for (int placemenT = 0; placemenT  < peopleInLine.size(); placemenT++)`

Comment: I see @user3365922 thank you very much.

Comment: I get numerous warnings about uninitialized variables when I compile it.

Fix those first and it may work.

Comment: I advise never to use weird capitalization. in worst case, use Oracle guides, but weird capitalization is one of pointers to "unmaintainable code".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> ```
> int twentyFiveS;
> int FiftieS;
> ```

These variables have indeterminate values, because you did not initialise them. Reading an indeterminate value has undefined behaviour.

> ```
> if (answer(placemenT, peopleInLine, FiftieS, twentyFiveS) == "NO") {
> ```

on this line, you pass copies of the indeterminate values into a function. The behaviour of the program is undefined.

> ```
>  for (int placemenT; peopleInLine.size(); placemenT++)
> ```

On this line, you increment an indeterminate value, which is also undefined behaviour. Furthermore, the loop end condition is wrong, because the size of `peopleInLine` never changes in the program, and thus cannot reach zero.

> So you're saying that I need to add a specific value to the variables (i.e. int twentyFiveS = 0; int FiftieS = 0; ?

You must initialise them with some value if you want to use their value. If you want that value to be 0, then initialise to that.

`placemenT` must at least be initialised to a value that is a valid index into `peopleInLinE` or else the behaviour will still be undefined. You must also make sure that the loop ends before accessing the vector out of bounds.

Comment: "Loops that never terminate also have undefined behaviour." really?

Comment: So you're saying that I need to add a specific value to the variables (i.e. `int twentyFiveS = 0; int FiftieS = 0;` ?

Comment: @user3365922 I reworded for more precision, but essentially, yes.

Comment: @jwjbadger You must initialise them with some value if you want to use their value. If you want that value to be 0, then initialise to that.

Comment: `Loops that unconditionally cannot terminate also have undefined behaviour` really? Loops that don't terminate just run forever, there's no UB there

Comment: @AlanBirtles endless loop with no side effect is UB, though this is not case, but body is also UB because uninitialized variables use, so whole thing is UB.

Comment: @AlanBirtles *"[intro.progress] The implementation may assume that any thread will eventually do one of the following: terminate, make a call to a library I/O function, perform an access through a volatile glvalue, or perform a synchronization operation or an atomic operation."*. It is my interpretation that not doing what implementation may assume is done will have UB. But indeed, if the loop does one of the other things besides terminating, it may be infinite. The loop in the example doesn't do any of those, but... :) I missed the fact that there are `return`s in the loop, so not infinite.

Answer (score 1):

Address Santizier is your friend.

```
$ g++ -ggdb3 -O0 so.cpp -fsanitize=address
$ ./a.out
AddressSanitizer:DEADLYSIGNAL
=================================================================
==8680==ERROR: AddressSanitizer: SEGV on unknown address 0x60200002002c (pc 0x555f1b4fd438 bp 0x7fffe57487f0 sp 0x7fffe57486d0 T0)
==8680==The signal is caused by a READ memory access.
    #0 0x555f1b4fd437 in answer[abi:cxx11](int, std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> >, int, int) /tmp/so.cpp:6
    #1 0x555f1b4fd9cc in tickets[abi:cxx11](std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> >) /tmp/so.cpp:36
    #2 0x555f1b4fdd83 in main /tmp/so.cpp:43
    #3 0x7f9c60e6beda in __libc_start_main (/lib64/libc.so.6+0x23eda)
    #4 0x555f1b4fd249 in _start (/tmp/a.out+0x2249)

AddressSanitizer can not provide additional info.
SUMMARY: AddressSanitizer: SEGV /tmp/so.cpp:6 in answer[abi:cxx11](int, std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> >, int, int)
==8680==ABORTING
```

The issue is that you're using an uninitialized variable (`placemenT`) as an index to `peopleInLine`.